# What is the client for spyne with json document protocol?

Tags: python, json, rpc, spyne

I'm trying with the [spyne hello world example](http://spyne.io/docs/manual/02_helloworld.html) , the codes basicly are:

```
class HelloWorldService(ServiceBase):
    @srpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=Array(Unicode))
    def say_hello(name, times):
        for i in range(times):
            yield 'Hello, %s' % name

application = Application([HelloWorldService],
              tns='spyne.examples.hello',
              in_protocol=JsonDocument(validator='soft'),
              out_protocol=JsonDocument()
          )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 7789, wsgi_app)
    print "rpc server start"
    server.serve_forever()
```

And I'm trying to connect to it with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) like:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:7789/sayhello"
data = { "name": "World", "times": 4 }
headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

It returns with 404.

But if I'm using HttpRpc protocol, the requests way is fine.

So how do I implement a client to use the Json Document protocol. Using the lib `requests` is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use JsonDocument as in_protocol, you should use this notation for send data...

```
data = { "say_hello" : { "name": "World", "times": 4 } }
```

It means that you should pass your function name as the main key in your json, and its content should be a json with the arguments of your function.

and your url should be the same, but without the function name i.e:

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:7789/"
```

if you want to check more stuff, could read the spyne blog at http://spyne.io/blog/

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I wish they would add this to demo code.

Answer (score 1):

I've just added request via JsonDocument protocol example to the http://spyne.io.

Check it out: http://spyne.io/#inprot=JsonDocument&outprot=JsonDocument&s=rpc&tpt=WsgiApplication&validator=true

For reference; you can do both:

```
curl http://localhost:7789 -d '{ "say_hello" : { "name": "World", "times": 4 } }'
```

or

```
curl http://localhost:7789 -d '{ "say_hello" : ["World", 4]}'
```

The argument order is the same as the argument order in the Python side.